# Align mysql results

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to get the results of my queries to show up like this.

```
here  here  here

here  here  here

here  here  here
```

... and so forth

But no matter what I try they end up like this..

```
Here

Here

Here

Here
```

and you get the picture... I honestly have tried everything and I can't get it to work.

Here's the code ignore my bad coding please :/

```
<div class="box">
<div style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
<div style="width: 33%; float: left;">

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$battle_get2['pic'].'" border=0>
</a>' ; 

$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);

?>

<form name="slot1" action="" method="post">

    <p>

        <select name="A" id="" >
          <option value="1">Slot 1</option>
          <option value="2">Slot 2</option>
          <option value="3">Slot 3</option>
          <option value="4">Slot 4</option>
          <option value="5">Slot 5</option>
          <option value="6">Slot 6</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php  echo $iddd ;  ?>" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Add to Team" name="slot1">
</p>



</form>

<?php
echo $row['pokemon'];

?>

<p></p>

<?php
echo "Level:";
echo $row ['level'];
?>

<p></p>

<?php
echo "Gender:";
echo $row['gender'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the css I have with it.

```
.box {
width: 90%;
background-color: #eaebd8;
border: 1px solid #00008B;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

So if I could get some help with this, I would VERY much appreciate it :)

Comment: Don't use <p> tags -- for this type of operation, just use a table with columns...

Comment: I've tried using tables before, it ended the same way, I don't know how to make the table with this type of thing, I'm pretty new.

Comment: You have a closing `</a>` tag, but no opening `<a>`. And don't do multiple mysql queries, do a single query with a JOIN.

Comment: i think `width: 90%;` will almost ate your width space result for the next division to float into the next row.

Comment: Is the 33% DIV supposed to be around each element you're displaying? Then you need to move that inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div that measures where everything is should be inside the loop so that it creates multiple.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
        <?php
        //enter the rest of your content
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Works, but isn't the best solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a table, or use an unordered list `ul`:

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/P5bAL/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>DAta</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Table or list is much better than other solution, +1.  There's not many occasions when tables make sense, but when trying to represent a database (which is a table) why would you use `<div>`

Comment: @SamSullivan Yeah I'm not sure, .... an `ul` is the perfect way for going about doing this. Anyways, as long as OP got it sorted...